# How to create a timer method with start and stop

Tags: scala

I want to execute a method every 5 seconds. I also need a start and stop

I am quite new to Scala so I don't have enough experience with timer object. I have played a bit with it but I do not have enough understanding of it

```
  val timer = new Timer()
  val run = timer.schedule(method(messageSender, "hello"), 5.Seconds)
  def method (messageSender: MessageSender, message: String): Unit ={
    messageSender.sendMessage(message)
  }

  run.start()
  run.stop()
```

I know the code is not correct. I just wrote how I think it would look like raughly.

run.start would start executing the method every 5 seconds. and run.stop would stop the execution. Anyone have a rough idea of how I can achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using akka actor I am doing it as follows

```
import system.dispatcher
val system = ActorSystem("mySystem", config)
//1 second as initial delay
system.scheduler.schedule(1 seconds, 5 seconds) {
taskToCall()
}
```

You can refer to this https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scheduler.html?language=scala